# How to get a light foggy look in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've some some great usage of photos lately, especially in website headers that are light, easy on the eye, and don't attract too much attention.  How can I create this same effect on my photos in photoshop cs6?

Examples here:

http://dribbble.com/shots/374899-Men-s-Retreat-Flyer?list=searches&tag=rugged
[image]

http://dribbble.com/shots/791728-Built?list=searches&tag=rugged
[image]

Comment: Add a white layer on low opacity or lower the opacity of the image layer with a white layer under it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scott in first comment is right. Image - just direction.

[image]

Comment: What is the brush hardness 0 in layer 3?

Comment: @user1676691 Select "Brush Tool" and right click on canvas. In popup change hardness to 0, and size to "halfsize-fullsize of canvas". On a new layer click 1 time with activated brush tool and play with opacity, layer blending mode and position of this layer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve the same effect by blurring the image,
(filter > blur > Gaussian blur) with a value between 0.5px and 1px

and then creating a new layer and filling it with white (edit > fill..) and change it's opacity to somewhere between 5%-20%.

You can also try to do a radial gradient from black to white and changing it's blend mode to screen.